# Counters not decrementing or not being read in Breakout

Tags: java

Okay, I've got this game loop which never terminates --

```
public void run() {
    setup();
    addMouseListeners();
    int Turns = NTURNS;
    int TotalBricks = NBRICKS_PER_ROW * NBRICK_ROWS;
    while ((Turns>0) && (TotalBricks>0)) {
        moveBall();
        checkForCollision();
        pause(DELAY);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

-- even though I have this method decrementing the Turns value every time the ball is missed:

```
private void checkForCollision() {
    GObject collider = getCollidingObject();
    if (collider !=null) {
        if (collider == Paddle) {
            vy= -vy;
        }
        else {
            vy= -vy;
            remove(collider);
            TotalBricks = TotalBricks - 1;
        }
    }
    if((ball.getX()>=(WIDTH-BALL_RADIUS)) || (ball.getX()<=0)) {
        vx = -vx;
    }
    if(ball.getY()<=0) {
        vy = -vy;
    }
    if(ball.getY()>=HEIGHT) {
    Turns = Turns -1;
    remove(ball);
    newBall();
    }

}
```

plus this

```
private int Turns;
```

at the bottom to ensure that the variable is shared among both methods.
No matter how many times the ball is missed, the game never stops.
What am I missing?
Thx

Comment: Just as a little note, it's always a good idea to accept an answer to let other people know the correct solution! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring your `Turns` variable twice, once for the entire class and once for the the `run()` method. Since you are also checking the value of the `Turns` variable that you've declared in the `run()` method, it never decreases because the one being used in `checkForCollision()` isn't the one that's being checked in the while loop.

In `run()`, this:

```
int Turns = NTURNS;
```

needs to be:

```
Turns = NTURNS;
```

Comment: Thanks. And with that, my game is complete, and now I can sell it to my mom and dad.

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring a new Turns variable in your run method which is what is getting used by that method since it has a more local scope. This is called variable shadowing. Use a decent Java IDE like Eclipse and it will warn you when you do this. It's almost always a mistake.

http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15

Comment: ah good - finally something to read! Thanks! The loop is now stopping. This shadowing has bit me twice now.